# Синтаксичний розбір речення. Кількість простих речень в одному складному

Tags: синтаксис

При розборі речення стикнулася з проблемою. У першій строфі пісні "Туман яром", що наводжу нижче є 2 простих речення чи 4?

> Туман яром, туман яром,
>
> Туман і горою,
>
> Сніжок випав білесенький
>
> Да й взявся водою.

Якщо ж би розширити речення до "туман яром стелиться", то вийде, підмет, обставина місця і присудок. Аналогічно і з наступною частинкою "туман стелиться і горою": підмет, присудок, обставина місця. Таким чином у половині срофи вже є 2 простих речення. Якщо ж брати буквально, "туман яром", "туман і горою", то можна трактувати, як підмет+обставина місця, які є однорідними членами речення.
Щодо другої частинки, то теж можна вважати, що "випав" і "взявся" - це однорідні присудки. Таким чином може вийти теж 1 речення з однорідними присудками. Якщо ж з другого боку поглянути, то можна вважати і так: перша частинка складного речення "сніжок випав білесенький" - підмет, присудок, означення, що складає двоскладне речення, а "да й взявся водою" - "да" у значенні підмета "взявся водою" - складений присудок.

Інформації в Інтернеті з таким прикладом не знайшла.

Допоможіть у вирішенні цього питання. Дякую!

Comment: На спорідненому сайті [linguistics.se] вважаються оффтопіком запитання виду «намалюйте мені синтаксичну діаграму цього речення». Щоб запитання стало відповідати формату, варто вказати, what have you tried so far і з якою конкретною проблемою стикнулися. (1) що спонукало вас до думки, що там 2 або 4? А не 42, наприклад? Якими є ваші попередні висновки? Що змушує сумніватися? (2) «інформації в інтернеті не знайшла» — а як шукали? А моʼ, не шукали? :-)

Comment: описала свої думки щодо питання. Правильно зараз чи ще щось додати?

Comment: Тепер усе чудово, дякую!

Comment: І Вам дякую, якщо критика розумна, результат виходить чудовий!))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Складне безсполучникове речення, перша частина "Туман яром" - просте неповне, друга частина "туман яром" - просте неповне, третя частина "туман і горою" - просте неповне, четверта частина "Сніжок випав білесенький / Да й взявся водою" просте повне з однорідними присудками.

У [Синтаксисі](http://shron1.chtyvo.org.ua/Shulzhuk_Kalenyk/Syntaksys_ukrainskoi_movy.pdf) Шульжук знаходимо визначення неповних речень, він виділяє для нашого випадку окремий тип - еліптичне речення, щоправда, цей тип визнають не всі дослідники, та нам це тут не так важливо, головне, що ми бачимо принцип для схеми простого неповного речення:

> Учені виокремлюють кілька різновидів неповних еліп­ тичних речень: 1)
>   з еліпсисом присудка (головного члбна односкладно­ го речення) зі
>   значенням дієслова руху, переміщення в просторі. За структурою такі
>   речення переважно поєдну­ ють препозитивну чи постпозитивну обставину
>   з підметом, постпозитивний додаток з підметом, напр.: А москалі їй
>   назустріч, як один, верхами (Т. Шевченко); Так мати мер­ щій до
>   хазяїна мене, в село одно (А. Тесленко); А біля шко­ ли тим часом ще
>   танці (О. Гончар). Деколи у простому і складному реченнях не
>   називаєть­ ся кілька присудків зі значенням руху, напр.: В ін поза
>   ставом, я — поза ним, він — у ліщинку і зник (С. Василь­ ченко)...

Щодо питання про підмет, то частина речення "Да й взявся водою" є сполучником (те саме, що "Та й") з присудком:

ДА 1, спол., діал.

1. єднальний. З'єднує однорідні члени речення або цілі речення. На селі стихло; хіба де стукне віконце да проскочить попід ворітьми хисткий парубок (Марко Вовчок, I, 1955, 71); Биймо да биймо панів з паненятами! (Павло Тичина, I, 1946, 218).

[СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/da)

Comment: Якщо наведені твердження на чомусь ґрунтуються, то варто наводити джерела. Якщо це власна думка, то вона не може бути основою відповіді (але може її доповнювати).